# MPI - How to avoid using two buffers in a non-blocking send & receive?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, mpich

I have a use-case where I need to transmit an Array of Structures (AoS) among a group of processors in a circular ("ring") fashion.
I do that currently by using a non-blocking send and receive, and using two auxiliary buffers on the senders and receivers side respectively.

Since the data I am transferring is extremely huge (~60 gb before partitioning), allocating two buffers seems inefficient to me. My question is -- Is there a better way to do it by avoiding "two buffers"? (Perhaps just using one buffer in some way?, so that I can reduce my memory requirement).

Roughly my communication procedure looks like this:

```
//Pack AoS into send buffer (which is a vector<char>)        
        char *msg_ptr = &(msg_send_buf_.front());
        for (auto& param : local_primal_params_) {
          param.pack_to(msg_ptr);
          msg_ptr += PARAM_BYTENUM;
        }

//Perform non-blocking send receive
        {
          MPI_Request send_request;
          MPI_Status send_stat, recv_stat;
          MPI_Isend(&(msg_send_buf_.front()), local_primal_params_.size() * PARAM_BYTENUM, MPI_CHAR,
                    send_to, 0,
                    MPI_COMM_WORLD, &send_request);
          MPI_Recv(&(msg_recv_buf_.front()), local_primal_params_.size() * PARAM_BYTENUM, MPI_CHAR,
                    recv_from, 0,
                    MPI_COMM_WORLD, &recv_stat);
          MPI_Wait(&send_request, &send_stat);
        }

//Unpack receive buffer back into AoS on receiver side
        {
          char *msg_ptr = &(msg_recv_buf_.front());
          for (auto& param : local_primal_params_) {
            param.unpack_from(msg_ptr);
            msg_ptr += PARAM_BYTENUM;
          }
        }
```

Any recommendations will be very helpful.

Comment: have you looked into defining the structs as their own MPI_Datatype? this way you could send your array of structs directly without requiring packing and unpacking

Comment: Unless you are willing to sacrifice performance - no. You might devise some clever segmenting scheme, e.g. first send a small segment from the beginning of the buffer, then start receiving in it while sending from the next segment, then receive in the next segment while sending the third one, and so on. If you are OK with losing performance, just use `MPI_Sendrecv_replace`.

Comment: You could take a look at RMA. Then you don't allocate any extra buffers on the application's side. You just drop the data directly into the target's memory.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. @Hristo: Your suggestion was really helpful. I was able to implement based on your suggestion! Great idea.. Thanks!